# How could a 'reverse-stile' work?

Tags: technology, engineering, transportation

How could a reverse stile, which is a gate that can be passed by hooved quadrupeds but not by humans, be built? The humans are modern humans, and will have the same equipment (limited to what they can carry on their person, and excluding probable weapons) and knowledge as us. The hooved quadrupeds using the stile need not be a real animal, but it should still be a plausible creature. It must be mostly mechanical, and should be simple enough that an amateur could build it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122762/discussion-on-question-by-ichthys-king-how-could-a-reverse-stile-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking essentially a security question.
How can you restrict access to a particular group? The three common factors are:

- some thing they know.
- some thing they are.
- Some thing they have.

Of course for all suggestions: No solution will stop determined tool users. As the saying goes, "Locks only keep honest people out".

#### Some thing they know.

Something that the live stock knows but people don't is difficult. On the futile side. Something that people know but livestock don't is easier. This would easily run into security by obscurity, relying on obscurity alone is very weak.

A sign stating "no entry: live stock only." would be somewhat effective.

#### Something they are:

- Smaller live stock The easiest have live stock that are smaller then people.  Chicken coops often have doors for the birds that most people can't use.
- Taller live stop:  A giraffe like animal could trigger a gate or walk over a fence.
- Climber: Think large slanted stone walls and mountain goats.

#### Something they have:

Equip livestock with RFID tags. The gate unlocks/opens on proximity.  The approach could be physically constrained such to keep it one animal at a time. Think turnstiles.  This I could see being used to monitor locations of pastured live stock.

#### Manned gate

The most sure way would be a manned gate, where there are people ensuring only specified goods, livestock pass. But of course by far the most expensive. Only in very few situations would this be practical.

Answer (score 1):

For piglet-sized hooved animals, such as minipigs and baby goats, use a dog door. You can build them with basic tools and most people won't be able to get through.

For cows and such, make a door that takes the force of a cow to push open, and which closes automatically.

For horses, make a barbed wire fence that they can leap over. Humans will need ladders to go over these, and the vast majority of humans don't carry ladders around.

Comment: What about rope?

Comment: What's stopping a bunch of humans from ganging up together and pushing the cow door? Doing things as a group to achieve an objective is something several animals do, us included.

Comment: Humans can get through most things. How high are the fences? What are they made of?  Humans have even been known to get through or over barbed wire without tools. The humans will simply bypass the gate. Nothing a quadruped can make will stop a human.

Comment: This is good answer based on the premise (like all stiles in present-day use) that the purpose of the stile isn't to keep something in a prison, but to keep the casually dishonest, honest (y'all should be thinking "subway stile" since an amateur can build one). +1

Comment: @JBH  -  According to the OP in a comment, *"These stiles would be used by the quadrupeds to restrict the motion of captured humans in their fields, without blocking off paths or land from the quadrupeds."*   Also, what stile can a *"hooved quadruped"* build?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica That's a good point. I missed it. But I still want details because now we're talking about an amateur building a turnstile to keep humans imprisoned. Sounds a bit oxymoronish - but if the captured humans were intellectually stunted (aka "Planet of the Apes").... I still like this answer.

Comment: A related option is to simply build *a ditch*, wide enough that humans can't jump over it. Although bridging it won't be impossible... I honestly don't think this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the *length* of the quadruped. Have a pressure plate on the ground about five feet from the gate that unlatches the gate. A quadruped can step on the plate with a rear leg and push the gate open in the same movement. A human would be stuck, because a human can't simultaneously apply sufficient pressure to the plate and push on the gate; the gate would re-latch before s'he could reach it.

It's not foolproof, obviously, but it's simple to implement, and good enough for low-security situations.

Comment: Works until the human pushes a rock onto the plate and walks through........

Comment: @Thorne: Obviously. But a cow with human-level intelligence could easily get past a normal turnstile by walking on its hind legs for a few feet. Something that works basically, and something that works against deliberate (intelligent) attempts at subversion... those are two entirely different questions.